# yaml to json conversion

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, yamldotnet

During implementation of yaml to json converter for swagger schema I was faced with the problem: default setup of deserialization builder

```
var deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder().Build()
```

cannot recognize 'integer', 'boolean' types. The deserializer converts those types to strings. For ex: i have yaml:

```
EntityId:
    type: integer
    example: 1245

EntityIds:
    type: array
    items:
        $ref: EntityId
    example: [152, 6542, 23]
```

The result of conversion is:

```
"EntityId":{
  "type":"integer",
  "example":"1245"
},
"EntityIds":{
  "type":"array",
  "items":{
    "$ref":"EntityId"
  },
  "example":[ "152","6542","23"]
}
```

but if I put input yaml to any of the online converters I get correct json result:

```
"EntityId": {
  "type": "integer",
  "example": 1245
},
"EntityIds": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "EntityId"
  },
  "example": [
    152,
    6542,
    23
  ]
}
```

also behavior for Boolean types.

The question is how to set up the deserializer for proper conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, this is not supported by YamlDotNet. There is work in progress to support [schemas](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Schema), which would enable this, but it is not yet complete.

Comment: do you have ETA ?